# DateTime field within 24 hours from a specific hour

Tags: apex, soql, datetime

it's a date time field `(my_date_field__c)`

I have to update the record if `my_date_field__c` is within the `past 24 hours` (`> yesterday at 5pm and <= today at 5pm`)

I was thinking to use a logic to add 5pm hours in YESTERDAY function to make it 5 pm from TODAY function

> select id,my_date_field__c from employee__c where my_date_field__c =
> TODAY and HOUR_IN_DAY(my_date_field__c ) = 5

but it does not seems to be working and for testing I set the `my_date_field__c` value to be `5/28/2021 5:00 PM`

Any idea how to achieve this soql/apex?

Comment: This is a date time field, right?

Comment: yes, its a datetime field, updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apex, just take away 24 hours:

```
Date last24Hours = DateTime.now().addDays(-1);
Employee__c[] employeesLast24Hours = [
  SELECT My_Date__c 
  FROM Employee__c 
  WHERE My_Date__c >= :last24Hours
];
```

If you really want the last 24 hours without a variable, it should look more like:

```
SELECT My_Date__c 
FROM Employee__c
WHERE My_Date__c = TODAY OR
 (My_Date__c = YESTERDAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c) > 17)
```

Remember to use 24 hour format; PM hours are the hour plus 12 (5 + 12 = 17).

Comment: the first query, i'm not sure this will work because I'm looking for a specific time like `5pm`  the second query looks promising but one question where are you checking to see if the my_date is within `past 24 hours (> yesterday at 5pm and <= today at 5pm)` ?

Comment: @NickKahn now() returns the current time, accurate to the millisecond. Adding -1 days will take you to exactly 24 hours ago. The second one, we're looking for everything "today" and everything "yesterday" after 5pm. If you also need to check for today up to 5pm, it'd be: `(TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)<17) OR (YESTERDAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)>=17)`

Comment: `Unexpected token '<'.`  here is what i got `SELECT My_Date__c 
FROM Employee__c WHERE My_Date__c = (TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)<17) OR (YESTERDAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)>=17)`

Comment: @NickKahn SOQL is strictly `FIELD = VALUE`. I see my previous comment had a typo or three. Try: `(My_Date__c = TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)<17) OR (My_Date__c = YESTERDAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(My_Date__c)>=17)`

Comment: I add `convertTimeZone` otherwise it was not catching the right number of hours. `HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(My_Date__c))`

Comment: @NickKahn Ah, that makes sense. I forgot about that. Still, that's why I'd use Apex and just add -24 hours/-1 day, it makes it time zone agnostic.

Comment: yes you're right I'm thinking more towards using the apex rather than soql, so if I go with apex route what would add or change the logic?

Comment: @NickKahn Nothing. Just use DateTime.now().addDays(-1), and bind it directly, as in my answer.